# Delayed Job inside model - Wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, delayed-job

Here is my model:

```
class User
  def join(race)
    #blah blah blah ....
    UserMailer.delay.join_race(self, race) #I'm stuck here
  end
end
```

And my UserMailer like this

```
class UserMailer
  def join_race(user, race)
    #Another blah blah blah, nothing important here
    mail(:to => user.email)
  end
end
```

Now, whenever I call `user.join(race)`, it shows the error like this:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
from /home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/expressions.rb:3:in `count'
from /home/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:224:in `binary?'
from /home/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:233:in `visit_String'
from /home/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:102:in `accept'
from /home/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:292:in `block in visit_Hash'
from /home/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:290:in `each'
 ...
```

If I convert it to normal function (without the `.delay` in front of `join_race`), it works.

I found similar issues but they are all about not calling `.all` method after using `where`. I suspect that the `self` could be the problem but I don't know how to make it work. If any of you have any clue, please share with me.

Comment: Please share at least the next line in the backtrace so that we can see what code is invoking the `count` method and passing two arguments instead of the allowed 1 (or 0).

Comment: Hi, I updated the stack trace. But I personally think there is no useful info from the stack trace. Hope that you will get something from them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because I am using Rails 3.2.12. It seems like this problem only occurs in this version of Rails. Therefore, I upgrade my project to Rails 3.2.13 and everything is working properly.

Comment: Glad you were able to get things working.  Did my answer provide any assistance ro you?   Inparticular, did you look at the second link I provided?

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the second link and the Rails version made me think about upgrading. Thanks

Comment: I'm on Rails 3.2.19 now and I'm seeing this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is discussed in https://github.com/rails/arel/issues/149, including a mention of Mailer and delayed jobs, and the related https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9263.

The following workaround was included:

```
module Arel
  module Nodes
    class SqlLiteral < String
      def encode_with(coder)
        coder['string'] = to_s
      end
      def init_with(coder)
        clear << coder['string']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have tried this workaround and it didn't work. I upgraded my project to Rails 3.2.13 and it solves this issue.